# Lambda can't send message to SQS

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

I'm having trouble sending a message to my SQS queue from my lambda
function. Here's my setup

- Lambda is connected to 3 public subnets in the default VPC
- A VPC endpoint for SQS exists

I'm trying to send a message via boto3 using the following:

```py
import json
import boto3

sqs = boto3.client("sqs")
sqs.send_message(
    QueueUrl="https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/012345678901/my_queue",
    MessageBody=json.dumps({"message": "hello"}),
)
```

The lambda is timing out (60s). While debugging, I noticed that the boto3
client is connecting to `eu-west-1.queue.amazonaws.com` rather than
`sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`, which I specified in the QueueUrl parameter.
Through further debugging, I noticed that `eu-west-1.queue.amazonaws.com`
resolves to a public address within the Lambda whereas
`sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` resolves to a private address. I don't
understand why this is happening.

Comment: You are in a public subnet with vpc but lambda should be in a private subnet with NAT gateway to communicate with internet.

Comment: @Lamanus, I don't want to communicate over the ipublic net. I created a VPC endpoint to be able to access SQS privately within my VPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question on [GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2172), so thanks to swetashre for answering me there. It turns out I needed to specify the endpoint URL when creating the SQS client.

```py
sqs = boto3.client("sqs", endpoint_url="https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")
```